# Zscaler API Json issue using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

See the below powershell code I am using so far.

```
$ZscalerURL = "https://ips.zscalertwo.net/cenr/json"
             $r = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ZscalerURL).'zscalertwo.net'
             $results = New-Object PSObject

              $r.parameters.psobject.Properties.Name | 
             ForEach{ 
                 Add-Member -InputObject $results -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $r.parameters.$_.Value 
             }
```

I am unable to get the json into a readable format using this method and a few others, I can't refer to $r.continent.city for example.

Have tried using convertfrom-json with invoke-webrequest and using a hacky method using a foreach loop
e.g. $americas=foreach ($name in $r.'continent : Americas'){$name}

Comment: It is not JSON. `$r.'continent : emea'.'city : amsterdam'` is how you would access data details for amsterdam. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what your expected output is. However, you can do something like the following by looping through all the continent properties and city properties. Then passing those continent and city names down to the network address objects.

```
$ZscalerURL = "https://ips.zscalertwo.net/cenr/json"
$r = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ZscalerURL).'zscalertwo.net'

foreach ($continent in $r.psobject.properties.name) {
    foreach ($city in $r.$continent.psobject.properties.name) {
        $r.$continent.$city |
            Select-Object @{n='Continent';e={($continent -split ':')[-1].Trim()}},@{n='City';e={($city -split ':')[-1].Trim()}},*
    }
}
```

---

If you want to list the continent and city properties as is without manipulation, you can leave off the `-split` method. The rest method response provides the continent property values as `continent : <continent name>`. Likewise, the city property values are `city : <city name>`. The `-split` method gets rid of the `continent :`  and `city :`  prefixes. Without manipulation, you'd retrieve a specific city's network address info by using the following syntax as an example:

```
$r.'continent : emea'.'city : amsterdam'
```

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion and foreach-object { add-content -Value $_.range -path $CachePath } inside of the  $r.$continent.$city object. I was looking to return a list of just the range property on each object. Thank you!